i dont have the GoogleProvider component in the "next-auth/providers/google" i have only GoogleProfile
i dont have the GoogleProvider component in the "next-auth/providers/google" i have only GoogleProfile  . if there is a new version or something that the googleprovider path have changed or something that can solve this probleme please tell me ,  here is the code exist in the next-auth/providers/google file

import type { OAuthConfig, OAuthUserConfig } from ".";
export interface GoogleProfile extends Record<string, any> {
    aud: string;
    azp: string;
    email: string;
    email_verified: boolean;
    exp: number;
    family_name: string;
    given_name: string;
    hd: string;
    iat: number;
    iss: string;
    jti: string;
    name: string;
    nbf: number;
    picture: string;
    sub: string;
}
export default function Google<P extends GoogleProfile>(options: OAuthUserConfig<P>): OAuthConfig<P>;
//# sourceMappingURL=google.d.ts.map


I tried to reinstall the next-auth but there still no GoogleProvider in "next-auth/providers/google" file

GoogleProvider exists in next-auth. Follow official documentation.
Make sure to install v4 of next-auth.
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
...
providers: [
  GoogleProvider({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
  })
]
...

if have any other error add a code snippet and error to the question.
